# Django. Confusion about redirections

Tags: django

Here is my simplified code:
project's urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^to_app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    url(r'^to_app2/', include('app2.urls')),
)
```

app1's urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from app1 import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.app1Page, name='app1-page'),
    url(r'^action/', views.app1_to_app2, name='app1-to-app2-page'),
)
```

app2's urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from app2 import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.app2Page, name='app2-page'),
)
```

app1's view:

```
def app1Page(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/app1page.html')

def app1_to_app2(request):
    # some actions going on here #
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/to_app2/')
```

app2's view:

```
def app2Page(request):
    return render(request, 'app2/app2page.html')
```

So, I have a button on app1page.html which should sends data through POST function to **to_app1/action/** url. In the end it should redirect me to app2page.html, but it does not. It gives me GET 127.0.0.1:8000/to_app2/ HTTP/1.0 200 OK, but I staying on the same page (app1page.html).

There is obviously something I missing, could someone point out it to me?

Comment: The first thing missing is your app1/app1page.html template. The second thing missing is the (possibly stripped down) code for `app1_to_app2` reproducing your problem. " Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "

Comment: Well, my question is why it does not working with the code I wrote. I thought this is enough for code to work. If templates just blank htmls and if there is no code for `app1_to_app2` except for `return` it still should work. The POST function also literally just `$.post('/to_app1/action/')`. That's it. It doesn't do anything useful, but redirection should work. But it doesn't.

Comment: Your comment illustrates Bruno's point. Your post left out the fact that you are doing an ajax post. Redirection doesn't work with Ajax, you'll need to get your js to change the window.location.